# error while installing visual studio 2015 RC

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I am getting following error during installation of visual studio 2015 RC.

[image: Error]

I am using windows 7 64 bit.

this is the error message in the log

[34D8:0C48][2015-06-03T00:25:16]e000: Error 0xc80003f3: Failed to execute MSU package.
[2358:3190][2015-06-03T00:25:16]e000: Error 0xc80003f3: Failed to configure per-machine MSU package.